# Proxy Server Connections via Python cx-Oracle

Tags: python, api, server, proxy, cx-oracle

I have a question regarding Python/cx-Oracle.

The Oracle SQLcl and SQL*Developer tools, both support proxy server connections (not to be confused with proxy users).
For example, on SQLcl their is a command line option, "--proxy", which is nothing to do with proxy users.

I can't say that I know exactly how they work, but the options are there, and I assume that there is an option in an API in there to support it.

Is this something which cx-Oracle supports?

Thanks,

Clive

I tried looking at the cx-Oracle docs, but couldn't spot anything which might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had another search through the docs and it appears that you are expected to make changes to oracle config files (sqlnet.ora and tnsnames.ora). That said, it also appears that newer EZconnect string syntax supports the proxy server requirement.